# Filter a list based on another list with multiple choices of elements

Tags: python, list, numpy

Suppose I have a list `a=[1, 3, 4, 5, 7]` and another list `b=[0,0,1,1,3]`.

Now I want to filter `a` to make a new list where the corresponding position in `b` is 0 or 3. If I only want `b` to be 0, it's simply `a = a[b==0]`, but now it's filtering based on a subset.
What I did is :

```
subset = [0, 1]
a = a[b in subset]
```

which is not correct and the error goes:`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I wonder what is the correct way to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right then you're looking for `np.isin`:

```py
a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 5, 7])
b = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 3])

print(a[np.isin(b, [0, 3])])
```

Prints:

```
[1 3 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [i[0] for i in zip(a,b) if i[1] in [0,1]]
```

This uses a concept known as list comprehension.

It first creates a zip object that looks like

```
[(1, 0), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 1), (7,3)]
```

The list comprehension cycles through all the tuples, and filters for all the ones where the second element is either 0 or 1. And returns the first part of that

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `filter`,

```
In [18]: d = dict(zip(a,b))
In [19]: list(filter(lambda x:d.get(x) in (0,1), d))
Out[19]: [1, 3, 4, 5]
```